# Error in AnnotationDbi::mget(id, GOANCESTOR) : use of NULL environment is defunct

Tags: r

I'm trying to run the `goplot`-function from the `enrichplot` package on my enrichment result from the Clusterprofiler analysis. However, when I run the code, a question mark pops up in the console. I don't understand what this means. Trying to understand this, I get the error:

> Error in AnnotationDbi::mget(id, GOANCESTOR) :
> use of NULL environment is defunct
> OR second argument must be an environment

What I've run as code before was

```
ego.LOUCY.reexpr <- enrichGO(gene          = reexpr,  ### this is my gene list
                             universe      = as.character(y$genes$GENEID.short),
                             OrgDb         = org.Hs.eg.db,
                             ont           = "ALL",
                             pAdjustMethod = "BH",
                             pvalueCutoff  = 0.01,
                             qvalueCutoff  = 0.05,
                             readable      = TRUE,
                             keyType = "ENSEMBL")
data(geneList, package="DOSE")
de <- names(geneList)[abs(geneList) > 2]
goplot(ego.LOUCY_drug.dmso.down)
```

I hope I provided enough and correct information.

Comment: I do not see where does `ego.LOUCY_drug.dmso.down`come from so it is difficult to help

Comment: Oh yeah, I just see I posted it wrong. I should have been ego.LOUCY_drug.dmso.down instead of ego.LOUCY_reexpr in the first row (had that run in my code though), so ego.LOUCY_drug.dmso.down basically is the result of the enrichGO analysis

Comment: Unfortunately your example is unreproducible because we do not have access to data. Please share an example of your dataset and give example of your universe

Comment: > head(y$genes$GENEID.short[which(dt.LOUCY_JQ1resistence.dmso != -1)])
[1] "ENSG00000000419" "ENSG00000000460" "ENSG00000000971" "ENSG00000001084"
[5] "ENSG00000001167" "ENSG00000001461"
> head(as.character(y$genes$GENEID.short))
[1] "ENSG00000000003" "ENSG00000000419" "ENSG00000000457" "ENSG00000000460"
[5] "ENSG00000000938" "ENSG00000000971"

I'm not quite sure if this is what you need... The enrichGO works, it's the goplot I have trouble with.